# Selenium evaluates DOM or Visible elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, nunit, phantomjs

I would like to understand how Selenium evaluates the page.

I have set of test to check elements on the page. Written with Nunit, Selenium and PhantomJS as Driver.

```
Page.Visit();
```

Page.FindElement(By.Id("testid").Text.Should().NotBeNull(); // PASS
    Page.FindElement(By.Id("testid").Text.Should().NotBeEmpty(); // does NOT PASS

The test DOES NOT pass if the browser size is set to be very small:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(10,10);
```

Based on this test, it is confusing how PhantomJS evaluates the page. I always thought that it checks the DOM but seems like for element TEXT it evaluates based on visibility!

Answer (score 1):

Although this surprised me too when I first discovered it, Selenium will only find elements visible in the viewport of the browser. For this reason, you will want to ensure at the start of your tests that your browser viewport is large enough to accommodate the content of your application.

Typically this can be done by maximizing the browser window. If you are using Windows, triggering the `F11` key via Selenium should work.

Comment: I found a blog post explaining that selenium gets only visible element text http://yizeng.me/2014/04/08/get-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-webdriver/